# How can I send an Email through Amazon SNS without confirming the Email address?

Tags: amazon-sns

We are building up a Micro Service where the users will be able to self-register through their email addresses. There will be a verification email sent by this Micro Service through which the user can verify the registered email address.

We plan to use Amazon SNS to send this email. However one issue we see is that right when we create a SNS subscription(email) to the SNS topic, Amazon itself sends an email(Subject: AWS Notification - Subscription Confirmation) with content similar to below:

```
You have chosen to subscribe to the topic: 
--------------------
To confirm this subscription, click or visit the link below (If this was in error no action is necessary):
```

We don't want this email to be sent by Amazon since we are anyway going to send a mail to that email address to verify that address.

Can anyone suggest how we can avoid this AWS Notification - Subscription Confirmation Email?

Thanks,
Ranjith

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are describing a use case for which SNS email is not appropriate.

Additonally, SNS supports only plaintext emails (no HTML) and the sender is always `no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com`.

This service is primarily intended for sending technical information to insiders -- such as network/system alerts and job/event-related notifications.

The appropriate tool for emails sent to guests of your web site or app is Amazon Simple Email Service (SES).